# Change a subview at run time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In the initialization of my view controller I declare a view and I set it as a subview of the main view:

```
self.customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:self.customView];
```

Later on, in a method I need to substitute `self.customView` for another view. (Note: changing the background color is just a simplified example. The views are more complex than that).

```
UIView *anotherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
anotherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.customView = anotherView;
```

But this has no effect. However if I instead make something like:

```
[self.view addSubview:anotherView];
```

It works fine. I want however to get rid of the previous view without localizing and removing the view explicitly. Isn't it possible to substitute a subview at runtime or I am missing something?

I work with ARC. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to find and remove the view explicitly? Do you fear performance issues or do you have any other concerns?

Comment: I do not wanted to removed it because it seemed more cleanear and because I thought it would be slower due to the search step along the view hierarchy (pretty complex right now). I was curious why was not possible to just substitute the view.

Comment: Maybe your anotherView gets positioned outside the bounds of your customView? You could try to use customView.bounds rather than self.view.frame in initWithFrame:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the best solution for you it is to write a custom setter to the @property customView:

in header:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* customView;
```

in impelementation:

```
@synthesize customView = _customView;
...
-(void) setCustomView:(UIView *)customView {
    NSUInteger z = NSNotFound;
    if (_customView) {
        z = [self.view.subviews indexOfObject:_customView];
    }
    if (z == NSNotFound) {
        // old view was not in hierarchy
        // you can insert subview at any index and any view you want by default
        [self.view addSubview:customView];
    } else {
        // you can save superview
        UIVIew *superview = _customView.superview;
        [_customView removeFromSuperview];
        //also you can copy some attributes of old view:
        //customView.center = _customView.center
        [superview insertSubview:customView atIndex:z];
    }
    // and save ivar
    _customView = customView;
}
```

So you will not need to add your customView as subview.
Also you will have the ability to replace your customView at any moment

Comment: This is an excellent answer assuming the actual need is more than just changing the background color.

Comment: Thanks I end up implementing this. Althought I am still curious why is not possible to directly substitute the view.

Comment: When you are trying substitute the view - old view removes from view hierarchy and new view just save in a property

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the old view and add the new view. Something like this:

```
// Remove old customView
[self.customView removeFromSuperview];

// Add new customView
UIView *anotherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
anotherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.customView = anotherView;
[self.view addSubview:self.customView];
```

Edit:

I didn't even notice that all you are doing is changing the background color. In this case there is no need to replace the view at all. Just update the background color:

```
self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Obviously, this is the (only) way to go, but the developer in question wants to avoid calling `removeFromSuperview` for some reason or another ..

Comment: @TimvanElsloo I don't think the OP wants to avoid calling `removeFromSuperview`. I think the OP was hoping that simply reassigning `self.customView` would magically also replace the view on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

instead of removing the old one and adding new one you can change the color of the old one, this will be more optimized rather that creating/removing view.

You can change the color of the view that is already added by following code

> self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

Comment: Thanks but I did not express myseld well enough about the color thing. It just pretended to be a simplification of a more complex different view.

Answer (score 0):

The example code you have shared I feel it is not the right way to code. Follow the sample code.

initialize both the view and set the hidden property

```
self.customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:self.customView];

self.customView.hidden = YES;

UIView *anotherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

anotherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[self.view addSubview:anotherView];

anotherView.hidden = YES;
```

During runtime choose your required view by

```
self.customView.hidden = NO;

anotherView.hidden = YES;
```

if you need self.customView to show

AND

```
anotherView.hidden = NO;

self.customView.hidden = YES;
```

if you need anotherView to show